# Remove folder name from rewritten URLs

Tags: htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, clean-urls

Consider this URL:

`http://example.com/gallery/20141111-some-title`

In this URL I want to hide `gallery/`:

`http://example.com/20141111-some-title`

How can I achieve this using *mod_rewrite*?

I used online generators for doing the rewrite rules but none can remove a piece of text from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gallery/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The rewrite rule should be the other way, it is `RewriteRule model substitution`. here you add /gallery/ at the beginning... (second)

Comment: @Zimmi When we enter `http://website.com/20141111-some-title`, we see the file that is in `http://website.com/gallery/20141111-some-title`. I think it's what we want, no?

Comment: I've understood the question the other way: the client asks for `http://website.com/gallery/20141111-some-title` and it is redirected with 301 to `http://website.com/20141111-some-title`. With the rule in the answer, the client asks `http://website.com/20141111-some-title` and receives `http://website.com/gallery/20141111-some-title` without 30x redirect, and may recieve the same content for both urls. I'm sorry if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Zimmi Yes, a complete answer would probably be to do Fabien's rewriting AND make a 301 so that the URL http://website.com/gallery/20141111-some-title is not accessible (and/or redirects to the one without 'gallery').

Comment: ...Although the URL should be "changed" in the website itself, not using mod_rewrite/.htaccess. .htaccess should only be used to route the URL and to perhaps catch/redirect URLs that have already been indexed or linked to by third parties. If you rely on .htaccess to "fix" the URL, without first fixing it in the website then _every_ time a user follows an internal link they will be externally redirected - which is bad for the user and the server (doubles the number of requests).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

These are the flags used:

```
L  - Last Rule
NC - Ignore (No) Case comparison
R  - External redirection (with 302)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^gallery/(.+)$ http://example.com/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Taken literally, this does appear to answer the OPs question (+1), however, whether the OP really intends to do this is another matter. (Since without further internal rewrites this probably just results in a 404.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /gallery/
  RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*) gallery/20141111-some-title$1 [L,R=301]
```

I hope this will works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this into .htaccess it's work for me

```
#testing
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+folder/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^folder/)^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L,NC]
```